# Exchange 2007 Database Restore

Tags: exchange-2007

We have a Recovery Storage Group. Within that group is a DB called 'Recovery.edb'. Due to a lack of space on other SG's we have had to move live users into this DB, and will continue to do so until we migrate to Exchange 2010, and new storage.

Now, I have an issue where I need to restore a mailbox from backup and to do that, I need to restore into the RSG. My question is, if I do that, will it affect the current users in recovery.edb ?

I'm not 100% how the RSG works as I'm not a full blown Exchange Admin - but learning as I go.

Thanks